# What is field template in ASP

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

**[MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/validation) says:**

> The DataType attribute can enable the ASP.NET Core framework to choose
>   the right **field template** to render the data. The DisplayFormat if used
>   by itself uses the string template.

What is field template?

Answer (score -1):

The [DataType attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.datatypeattribute?view=netframework-4.8) only provides hints for the view engine to format the data .The DataType attribute is used to **specify a data type that's more specific than the database intrinsic type**. DataType attributes are not validation attributes .

The DataType Enumeration provides for many data types, **such as Date, Time, PhoneNumber, Currency, EmailAddress, and more**. The DataType attribute can also enable the application to automatically provide type-specific features. For example, a mailto: link can be created for DataType.EmailAddress. A date selector can be provided for DataType.Date in browsers that support HTML5.